# How many processes are created by this program, and by which processes are they created by?

Tags: c, process, parent-child

I am tracing this program and determining how many processes are created (assuming no errors occurred).  I drew a graph to visualize the processes. In my graph, the first process created by the first `fork()` contains a `1`, and I have arrows pointing to each child process, from each respective parent.  Does this look correct?

Code:

```
 1: child2 = 0;
 2: child1 = fork();     // fork 1
 3: if (child1 == 0)
 4: {
 5:     child2 = fork(); // fork 2
 6: }
 7: fork();              // fork 3
 8: if (child2 > 0)
 9: {
10:     fork();          // fork 4
11: }
```

Graph:

```
                 0
                /|\
               / | \
              1  3  4
             / \  \
            /   \  \
           2     3  4
          /     /
         /     /  
        3     4
       /
      /
     4
```

Rationale

- The 1st `fork()` command on line 2 created child `1`.
- The 2nd `fork()` command on line 5 created child `2` only for `1`, because of `if(child1 == 0)`, i.e., the only process to have `fork()` return 0 to `child1` is `1`.
- The 3rd `fork()` command on line 7 created child `3` for `0`, `1`, and `2` because that statement was executed by each process.
- The 4th `fork()` command on line 10 created child `4` for every process except `2`, as each process has a copy of `child2` which was returned a positive value from `fork()`, except for `2`, which would have a 0 in `child2`.

What do you think?  Did I interpret this code and graph it correctly?

**UPDATE**

Correct graph is:

```
                 0
                / \
               /   \ 
              1     3
             /|\ 
            / | \  
           2  4  3  
          /       \
         /         \
        3           4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my interpretation, you can decided if it matches yours, I don't quite follow saying like "created child `3` for `0`, `1`, and `2`" since each would be a separate child.

My copy of your code:

```
int main(void) {
    int child2 = 0;
    int child1 = fork(); // fork 1
    if (child1 == 0)
    {
        child2 = fork(); // fork 2
    }
    fork();              // fork 3
    if (child2 > 0)
    {
        fork();          // fork 4
    }
    printf("%jd\n", getpid());
}
```

Graph:   (Parent left, child right)

```
|      
|\_____ // fork 1
|      |
|      |\______ // fork 2
|      |       |
|\__   |\__    |\__ // fork 3
|   |  |   |   |   |
|   |  |\  |\  |   | // fork 4
|   |  | | | | |   |
```

Comment: Thanks.  I see now where I made my mistake.  I think your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The `pstree` command applied to your example shows:

```
       bash-+-a.out-+-a.out-+-a.out---a.out
                    |       |-a.out---a.out
                    |       `-a.out
                    `-a.out
```

which would look like the following to have only one process per line.

```
       bash-+-a.out-+---------------------
                    +-a.out-+-------------
                    |       +-a.out-------
                    |       |      `-a.out
                    |       |-a.out-------
                    |       |      `-a.out
                    |       `-a.out-------
                    `-a.out---------------
```

which, after branch reordering, matches @Macattack's answer.

Note that you have no information about the relative timings of the process creations in the above graph;it is just the final result.

To understand the graph, let's look at the tree after a parent process forks:

```
int main(void) {
    int child1 = fork();
}
```

The result is:

```
  bash-+-a.out---a.out
         ^ parent   ^child
```

then, if the child forks again,

```
int main(void) {
    int child2 = 0;
    int child1 = fork();
    if (child1 == 0)
        child2 = fork();
}
```

we get:

```
  bash-+-a.out---a.out---a.out
         ^ parent   ^child  ^grandchild
```

But if the parent forks again wile the child does not,

```
int main(void) {
    int child2 = 0;
    int child1 = fork();
    if (child1 > 0)
        child2 = fork(); 
 }
```

we get:

```
  bash-+-a.out-+-a.out  <- child1
           ^   `-a.out  <- child2
           parent
```

Note that `pstree` compresses the output by merging identical siblings ; you need to use the `-c` option to prevent that and see the full tree.

Comment: Never even knew such a command existed. Further proof of my theory that there is a command for anything you could ever want to do on linux ;)